# Need help understanding the birthday problem

Tags: probability

I am not understanding the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

There are ${23 \choose 2} = 253$ ways of finding a pair in 23 people.

The probability of any two people having the same birthday is $\frac{1}{365} \times \frac{1}{365}$

The probability of existing one pair in 23 people having the same birthday is:
$(\frac{1}{365} \times \frac{1}{365}) + \dots + (\frac{1}{365} \times \frac{1}{365}) = 253 \times \frac{1}{365} \times \frac{1}{365} = 0.00189904297
$

If this is wrong. Then the above number I just calculated is the probability of what? I am confused.

Comment: The probability of two people having the same birthday is not $$\left({1\over 365}\right)^2,$$ it is $${1\over 365}.$$ The thing is that you didn't specify which day the birthday was. If you take that into account, the rest of the problem should resolve itself.

Comment: @SuzuHirose why? please explain more

Comment: Think about it for a bit.

Comment: I think this should be similar to throwing two dice and both come 6. Then probability is $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: No it's like throwing two dice and they both have the same number, which could be 1,2,3,4,5 or 6.

Comment: @SuzuHirose now makes sense. Thank you so much

Comment: I will post this discussion as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability of two people having the same birthday is not $$\left({1\over 365}\right)^2,$$ it is $${1\over 365}.$$ The thing is that you didn't specify which day the birthday was. If you take that into account, the rest of the problem should resolve itself.

It's not like throwing two dice and they both come out as six, it's more like throwing two dice and they both have the same number, which could be 1,2,3,4,5 or 6

Comment: I mean,  if we want to be pedantic it's 1 in 365.2425, but who's counting :).

Comment: Yes, I didn't take account of people born on February 29 in this answer, but the details can be filled in for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question in the body of your question:

Your calculation is not the calculation of some *probability*.

It is the calculation of the *expectation* of the number of pairs among $23$ persons (different than you) that consist out of $2$ persons *having the same birthday date as you have*.

This by applying linearity of expectation.

To see clear that it is not a probability do the same thing for some $n$ persons where $n$ is large enough to satisfy $\binom{n}2>365^2$.

Then your calculation results a value that exceeds $1$ but probabilities never exceed $1$.